# How to obtain adbkey.pub from the private key?

Tags: adb, rsa

I'm trying to make a script that will take control of an android device in a farm with `adb connect` making the connection through [OpenSTF](https://github.com/openstf/stf). One of the requirements for the device to accept the connection from a client is to provide the content of adbkey.pub in OpenSTF.

However, it seems that newer versions of ADB do not generate this file anymore, only the private key. From what I could collect from the AOSP repository, this is intentional https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_system_core/commit/2dc4cabe0639c71014d729dd92eff19289429c89

After reviewing the AOSP commit I realized that ADB keypairs are made with the RSA protocol, and I found an example of how to obtain the public key from the private [in this Stack Exchange question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/172274/can-i-get-a-public-key-from-an-rsa-private-key). However, the format of the public key for the OpenSSL output and the adbkey.pub are different. At first I thought that it's just encoded in base64 but even with this the outputs don't match.

This is an example of an ADB public key from `adb keygen` using an older version of ADB.

```
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 carolinadp@carolinadp-GL62M-7RD
```

And this is a public key made with OpenSSL from the same private key

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAsHxcUuIXBqAxzgsT7nM8
fAnwajZ+zzL8DEohJM5+gdC+Ll1pThuN+rlNPIQnGhquYoxqCrDKQyy3RwQOFAz8
Py3MmWBvHhoe8KwucUHdyE6Pzt3rsvYzvamvQBe4ZNNq8npZvyICjAj8JfDILSQv
0nkRVYyS5of7o7AIweZUzaII3dtMyP/+bx/6mmyrEaj3Uy9GiZgfUZsg8oqtQXDd
KemXo6YvODvOyG+a5l+ernKUrf8fxi79KUblTgEolFBDBU1gestTQViP1smoPxII
XqZAVYTODr4T81KKnPe2sRkJwms+HdumMSXDIKErnqwI91Hab1i6SumIELNhHmLv
JQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

How can I obtain the ADB public key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the "Connection refused" problem on OpenSTF when my adb version is upgraded to Version 28.0.2-5303910（so the adbkey.pub is gone）

```
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.40
Version 28.0.2-5303910
```

and now I finally solved it just by upgraded adb to the latest version

```
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 29.0.6-6198805
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use adb to generate a new private and public key pair (assuming linux):

```
cp ~/.android/adbkey ~/.android/adbkey.bak (backup existing key)  
rm ~/.android/adbkey
cd $ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
./adb keygen adb
```

Note:
I am assuming you have setup android sdk on the machine where you would like to generate the adbkey.pub, hence the existing $ANDROID_HOME path

Comment: `adb keygen adb` it's not available anymore, use `adb pubkey ~/.android/adbkey > ~/.android/adbkey.pub`

Answer (score 0):

You can use ssh-keygen to retrieve public key from your private key, like this:

> ssh-keygen -y -f adbkey > adbkey.pub

Maybe you need to remove the “ssh-rsa ” from the generated pub key file.

Comment: I tried generating a new keypair in an older adb version with `adb keygen test` and then your command `ssh-keygen -y -f test > testssh.pub` but test.pub and testssh.pub are still different. The public key made by adb is much longer. Either it is in some ADB-specific formatting or I am wrong about the protocol.

Comment: You can just try, I think the length is determined by keysize.